# Type list needs unchecked conversion to conform to List <Node>

Tags: java, xml, list, dom4j

I'm trying to parse a xml file using SAXReader. I'm having trouble generating a node list using elements. The IDE prompts the warning "List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List"

I tried using the simple org.w3c.dom parser and there was no problem parsing the xml file and it worked fine. But using SAXReader there was problem generating list.

This is the XML script

```
<class>
   <student rollno = "393">
      <firstname>dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>kad</lastname>
      <nickname>dinkar</nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
   </student>
</class>
```

This is the parser

```
         File inputFile = new File("input.xml");
         SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
         Document document = reader.read( inputFile );

         System.out.println("Root element :" + document.getRootElement().getName());

         Element classElement = document.getRootElement();

         List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/class/student" );
         System.out.println("----------------------------");

         for (Node node : nodes) {
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :"
               + node.getName());
            System.out.println("Student roll no : " 
               + node.valueOf("@rollno") );
            System.out.println("First Name : "
               + node.selectSingleNode("firstname").getText());
```

The IDE prompts warning on this line

```
List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/class/student" );
```

And the console log prints the first sysout that shows the root element but shows the following stacktrace

```
Root element :class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/NamespaceContext
    at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.createXPath(DocumentFactory.java:230)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.createXPath(AbstractNode.java:207)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.selectNodes(AbstractNode.java:164)
    at domParsing.EgParser.main(EgParser.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.NamespaceContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

(EgParser.java:25) is

```
List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes("/class/student" );
```

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with the error: it just tells you that the compiler can't check if the list returned by selectNodes() is indeed a List<Node>. The error means that some necessary jar library (jaxen) is not in your runtime classpath.

Comment: thanks @JBNizet importing jaxen resolved the issue.